# Lost static wlan0 IP when unplug ethernet?

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-stretch

I do not know why, but when I unplug my ethernet cable, I have no more wifi connection.
I use /etc/network/interfaces for configure my static IP

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.XXX.XX0
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.XXX.XXX

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.XXX.XX1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.XXX.XXX
   wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And my wpa_supllicant.conf is correct

Does anyone know why?
Thanks

Comment: What OS/release? What evidence - you have posted no stats. There is no point in being coy about a private IP. Probably 80% of users are using the same. Why did you ignore the warning "# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'"? What else have you changed?

Comment: Hi Milliways, i'm very sorry, i'm very noob :-(
I think I found by configuring my dhcpcd.conf as follows
eth0 interface
static ip_address = 192.168.104.20 / 24
static routers = 192.168.104.9
static domain_name_servers = 192.168.104.9 8.8.8.8

wlan0 interface
static ip_address = 192.168.104.21 / 24
static routers = 192.168.104.9
static domain_name_servers = 192.168.104.253 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, I have this in my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I'm wondering if adding auto wlan0 might help here.

Comment: Don't use the dhcp bit as you are using static/manual IP address assignment whereas I use dhcp.  I just wanted to paste working code, that was all.